# YouTube subscribe button - event 'onytevent' not firing

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I have got a strange issue with YouTube subscribe button. It seems like a bug on Google's side.

I have a simple code, copied (and slightly modified) from [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button): [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0kwrL5d/).

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div id="yt-console">Console: </div>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>

<script>
  function onYtEvent(payload) {
    var c = document.getElementById('yt-console');
    c.innerText += ' event';
    if (payload && payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
      c.innerText += ' subscribe';
    } else if (payload && payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
      c.innerText += ' unsubscribe';
    }
  }
</script>
```

The button looks different on FF and on Chrome (subscribers counter), but the main problem is that events mechanism is not working. Function *onYtEvent*  is never called. Anyone has any idea for a quick fix to make it working?

Comment: What about is not working?  Seems to work just like it does on the sample page.  I don't see why it _would_ call your function.  There is no event listener.

Comment: You are wrong. The attribute _data-onytevent="onYtEvent"_ determines the name of a function that should be called when an event occurs. Just a moment ago I noticed that in the english documentation this functionality is tagged as deprecated. What's interesting (and confusing...), for some languages (for example for italian - you can select language at the bottom of page) Google still doesn't inform about this fact - [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/reference)

Answer (score 2):

on the youtube reference it says it has been depricated:

"Note: The Subscribe Button's subscribe and unsubscribe events have been deprecated. Similarly, the data-ytonevent attribute, which could previously be added to the widget element to specify a listener for event notifications, has also been deprecated."

source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/reference